# show progress percentage on progress bar

Tags: javascript, css

I have some HTML file with css and javascript, it shows progress bar depending on project start date, end date and current date, it works fine but I need that progress percentage to show into the bar.

there is my file content:

```
    <html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <style type="text/css">
    .meter {
    height: 20px;
    /* Can be anything */
    position: relative;
    margin: 60px 0 20px 0;
    /* Just for demo spacing */
    background: #555;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    box-shadow : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.meter > span {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    background-color: rgb(43, 194, 83);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(43, 194, 83)), color-stop(1, rgb(84, 240, 84)));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(43, 194, 83) 37%, rgb(84, 240, 84) 69%);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.meter > span:after, .animate > span > span {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.25, transparent), color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, transparent), to(transparent));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
    -moz-background-size: 50px 50px;
    -webkit-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.animate > span:after {
    display: none;
}
@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0% {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 50px 50px;
    }
}
.orange > span {
    background-color: #f1a165;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f1a165, #f36d0a);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #f1a165), color-stop(1, #f36d0a));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f1a165, #f36d0a);
}
.red > span {
    background-color: #f0a3a3;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #f0a3a3), color-stop(1, #f42323));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0a3a3, #f42323);
}
.nostripes > span > span, .nostripes > span:after {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    background-image: none;
}
  </style>

  <title>Date to Percentage Progress</title>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

var targetDate = new Date("07/12/2017");
var beginDate = new Date("04/20/2017");
var totalTime = (targetDate - beginDate);
$(function () {

    //Create a custom event on the span to handle incoming data for animation.
    $(".meter > span").bind("progress-event", function (e, data) {
        $(this)
            .width($(this).prop("width"))
            .data("origWidth", data.Complete)
            .animate({
            width: $(this).data("origWidth") + "%"
        }, 1200);
        $(this).prop("title",($(this).data("origWidth") + "%"));
    });
    //Initial animation on page load.
    $(".meter > span").each(function () {
        $(document).trigger("date-changed", {
            Date: new Date()
        });
    });

    //Apply the datepicker with an event handler for a selected date
    $("#date-input").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (selectedDate, obj) {
            $(document).trigger("date-changed", {
                Date: selectedDate
            });
        } // end onSelect function
    });
});

//Custom event to handle a date being picked from the datepicker
$(document).bind("date-changed", function (e, data) {
    var dateProgress = new Date(data.Date) - beginDate;
    var completionPercentage = (Math.round((dateProgress / totalTime) * 100));
    if(completionPercentage > 100) {  //Make sure we don't go past 100
        completionPercentage = 100;
    } // end if
    $(".meter > span").trigger("progress-event", {
        Date: data.Date,
        Complete: completionPercentage
    });
});
//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="meter"> <span></span>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How and where this _progress percentage_ should be shown?

Comment: this is construction company site, this progress bar shows building progress automatically depending on start, end and current dates.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already using jquery. I would suggest to use jQueryUI progressbar UI widget and refer this example from the official jQueryUI website.

https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#download

I hope this helps.